# Variable assigned to DatePicker doesn't return value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need get `Date` in `DatePicker` and save it in `Database`

In `View` I have

```
<DatePicker Name="Data" Text="{Binding Path=Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In `ViewModel` I have

```
public DateTime Data
{
    get
    {
        return item.data;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != item.data)
        {
            item.data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Data); powoduje zmiane na interfejsie
        }
    }
} 
...
...

ATMAEntites.Wydarzenia.Add(item);
```

In database type is `Date`. If I create `Breakpoint` after add to database, item.data is {01.01.0001 00:00:00}

If I try save data from `DatePicker`  to string it return `null`. Other controls in `View` work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind SelectedDate property of DatePicker to you Data property in ViewModel.

```
<DatePicker Name="Data" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

As it is now you are binding string to DateTime and since he cannot convert it he is setting the default DateTime which is {01.01.0001. 00:00:00}.

Comment: Great! It's work. One more small question. It is possible set the default start date. Now it is 1.1.0001

Comment: You need to define that in the model since the control is now binded to the model.